# Changing the avatar of the bot in Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to replace the avatar image of the bot when a user runs a command. How would I do this? I have managed to replace the nickname but not the image.

```
await ctx.guild.me.edit(nick=nick)
```

^ Replaces the nickname.

I tried (nick=nick, avatar=avatar) but it did not work.

EDIT:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.id == second_server:
        await ctx.guild.me.edit(nick=nick, avatar_url=avatar)
        pfp_path = "Profile-Picture.png"
        with open(pfp_path, "rb") as pfp:
            await client.user.edit(password=None, avatar=pfp.read())
            print("profile picture changed")
```

Comment: What kind of object was `avatar`?

Comment: Its a link to a PNG image

Comment: You cannot give a URL directly, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit), the following should work:

```
import discord
  
client = discord.Client()

token = '...'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    pfp_path = "file.jpg"
    with open(pfp_path, "rb") as pfp:
        await client.user.edit(password=None, avatar=pfp.read())
    print("profile picture changed")

client.run(token)
```

You cannot directly give a URL to the desired profile picture.

**Note:** the only formats supported are JPEG and PNG

Comment: I got the error - AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'edit_profile'

Comment: Sorry, wrong method name! It's `client.edit` and not `client.edit_profile`

Comment: Lol got this now - AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'edit'

Comment: Hmm :/ Am I supposed to import anything or something like that?

Comment: the `edit` method is from class `discord.ClientUser`. If your Bot object is type `discord.Client` that object can fetch the user object with the property `.user` and you should be able to call the edit method on that.

Comment: @Karhu12 is right, and I'm sorry I did not think of that earlier. I updated the code to match that after testing it

Comment: Sorry I didnt respond earlier it was late for me. I tried it. I do not get an error and it prints "profile picture changed" But the picture was still the same. I added the PNG to the same folder as the script and set the pfp_path to "Profile-Picture.png". I tried about 3-4 times and then got this error ```400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In avatar: You are changing your avatar too fast. Try again later.```

Comment: I updated the post above with the code I have put. Maybe you can check it.

Comment: That's understandable. That means you've made to many calls to the "edit profile" API endpoint in too little time. Where did you put that code? What I gave was a usage example, but for instance you should probably put it in a command so it doesn't run every time your bot logs on. Do you see what I mean?